# private method `select' called for "Walt":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to loop through a block that will go through phrases and see if tweets include them. If tweets include the phrases, they should receive the 'redacted' div class. However, I keep receiving a `private method select called for "Walt":String` error. I'm a newbie so please bear with my code.

View:

```
<section id="tweets">
  <ul>
<% tweet = @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
@<%= tweet.user.screen_name %>
<%= image_tag(tweet.user.profile_image_url) %>
  <li><%= link_to tweet.text, "https://www.twitter.com/#{tweet.user.screen_name}=twitter&include_entities=true" %></li>
```

```
     <% for blockedshows in current_user.blockedshows %>
        <%= blockedshows.phrases %>
        <% for phrases in blockedshows.phrases %>
            <%= blocked = phrases.text %>
            <%= result = blocked.select do |b| %>
                <%= tweet.include? b %>
            <% end %>

        <% end %>

        <% if result.empty? %>
            <%= tweet %>
        <% else %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, class: 'redacted') {tweet} %>

        <% end %>

    <%end %>
```

Model

```
class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tvshow
  belongs_to :blockedshow

  def select

  end
end
```

Comment: `select` method shell be called for `Array`, `Hash`, or each `Enumerable`, not for `String` as is in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable blocked already contains the text you want to compare with the tweet and you are trying to execute the select method on it (which is a private method to the string class).

Refactoring your code a bit

```
<% current_user.blockedshows.each do |blockedshow| %>
     <% blockedshow.phrases.each do |phrase| %>
          <% if tweet.text.include? phrase.text %>
               <%= content_tag(:div, class: 'redacted') {tweet} %>
          <% else %>
               <%= tweet %>
          <% end %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the refactored code and now am getting a `undefined method `include?' for #<Twitter::Tweet id=415568707847716864>` error

Comment: Fixed by adding if tweet.text.include?